# nested interval theorem and Half-Closed nested Intervals?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

- Consider the family $A_n = (0, \frac{1}{2n}]$. We have $A_{n+1}
     \subset A_n$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and the length of $A_n$
  approaches zero as $n$ approaches infinity, is
  $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$ empty or not? Please give a proof !
- Every $A_n$ above is of positive length, thus I guess it is impossible for
  the intersection of all nonempty interval $A_n$ to be empty, is my
  reasoning right ?

P.S. Since the case here doesn't satisfy the conditions required for the nested interval theorem, so I cannot use the theorem to judge whether $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$ is empty or not here.

Answer (score 2):

You can just directly check if it is empty or not. For an element to be in $\cap^\infty_{n=1} A_n$ it needs to be in each $A_n$.

Let $x \in \mathbb R$. If $x \le 0$ then $x \not \in A_n$ for any $n$, so $x \not\in\cap^\infty_{n=1} A_n.$ If $x > 0$, then there is some $N$ so that $\tfrac 1 {2N} < x$. But then $x \not \in A_N$ and so $x \not\in\cap^\infty_{n=1} A_n.$ Thus the set is empty.